# How do I use interactive seaborn palettes in jupyter?

Tags: python, seaborn, jupyter

I want to play around with palette colors. What are the available commands for me in jupyter to select palettes (preferably using colorwheels, and if it is with input, with input like "yellow") and how do I assign the palettes after?

For instance, I was able to use this command `sns.choose_cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True)` to bring up a widget. But how do I then use this palette in a plot later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the output of the function to a variable

```py
cmap = sns.choose_cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True)
sns.heatmap(..., cmap=cmap)
```

The `cmap` object will persist across interactive updates, so you can call the first line once and then iterate on the heatmap call as you adjust the sliders in the widget.

But this won't be robust across repeated runs of the notebook, so you'll need to eventually define a colormap using the values you settle on and use that for any work you need to be reproducible.